# json.Marshal returning strange results

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to convert go structures to JSON.  I thought I knew how to do it, but I'm confused by the output of this program.  What am I missing?

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Zoo struct {                                                                       
    name string
    animals []Animal
}
type Animal struct {
    species string
    says string
}

func main() {
    zoo := Zoo{"Magical Mystery Zoo",                                                   
         []Animal {
            { "Cow", "Moo"},
            { "Cat", "Meow"},
            { "Fox", "???"},
        },
    }
    zooJson, err := json.Marshal(zoo)
    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(zoo)
    fmt.Println(zooJson)
}
```

Output:

```
{Magical Mystery Zoo [{Cow Moo} {Cat Meow} {Fox ???}]}
[123 125]
```

Expected Output (something along the lines of):

```
{Magical Mystery Zoo [{Cow Moo} {Cat Meow} {Fox ???}]}
{
    "name" : "Magical Mystery Zoo",
    "animals" : [{
             "name" : "Cow",
             "says" : "moo"
         }, {
             "name" : "Cat",
             "says" : "Meow"
         }, {
             "name" : "Fox",
             "says" : "???"
         }
    ]
 }
```

Where is `[123 125]` coming from?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result of marshaling is `[]byte` so `123` and `125` is ascii for `{` and `}`

Struct fields have to be exported for marshaling to work:

> Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object

Comment: This is something I have missed with golang-structs. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

Your problems is in unexported (call it non-public if you want) fields in your structs. [Here is the example on Go Play](http://play.golang.org/p/_ObTZ4H7WW) how you can fix it.

Also, if you don't like how your JSON fields named (capital letter in the most cases) you can change them with a struct tags (see [json.Marshal doc](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)).